# How do gulp pattern recursive work **/*

Tags: javascript, gulp, pattern-matching, file-globs

i started to use gulp, i have a little difficulty understand how globs work in gulp.

Why do `**/*` copy all directory structure(how it work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gulp uses the [glob module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob). Rules for globbing can be found [in its repo](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer).

> - `*` Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion
> - `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

`**` means "recursively descend through subdirectories" while `*` means "match any path".

Answer (score 2):

Extending your folder structure  `css/**/*.css`

`**` means recursive.

This means your telling gulp to go inside **css folder and all it's subdirectories** and  compile all files that has an extension .css